# Databinding not updating when called from $on

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding

I've got a weird bug that I can't quite figure out.  I recently refactored my angular app to be a bit more 'angular-ish'.  Part of that was moving a window resize event handler out of a directive and putting it into a .run block where it can broadcast Angular events to the whole application.

That part seems to work fine.  It watches the window and events propagate properly.  However, when I call my model manipulation code from the $on listener, the databindings don't seem to fire.

```
.controller('channelListController', function ($scope, $rootScope, $http, $filter){
  $http.get('api/v1/channels').success(function(data){
    $scope.baseChannels = data;

    filterChannelData($scope.filter);
    //call manually since initial window resize occurs before async return
    splitChannelData($rootScope.windowAttr.columns);
  });

  //*************
  //this part doesn't trigger databinding update
  //*************
  $scope.$on('columnChange', function(){
    //window resize requires changing column number
    console.log('change detected');
    splitChannelData($rootScope.windowAttr.columns);
  });

  //*************
  //but this does
  //*************
  $scope.$watch('filter', function(newVal){
  //the filters are changed
    filterChannelData(newVal);
    //re-run split for new data
    splitChannelData($rootScope.windowAttr.columns);
  }, true);

  function filterChannelData(filter){
    if(filter){
      $scope.filteredChannels = $filter('looseCreatorComparator')($scope.baseChannels, filter.creators);
      $scope.filteredChannels = $filter('looseTagComparator')($scope.filteredChannels, filter.tags);
    } else {
      $scope.filteredChannels = $scope.baseChannels;
    }
  }

  function splitChannelData(columns){
    if(columns){
      $scope.splitChannels = [];
      for(var rep=0;rep<columns;rep++){
        $scope.splitChannels.push([]);
      }
      _.forEach($scope.filteredChannels, function(channel, index){
        $scope.splitChannels[index % columns].push(channel);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

So, when I alter the contents of my filter input fields, the $watch catches that, runs my filters and then fires splitChannelData.  The latter refactors my dataset into a set of separate arrays for display.  The view is databound to $scope.splitChannels.  This works fine.

However, when the broadcast 'columnChange' event is caught by $on, the splitChannelData function fires, properly refactors $scope.splitChannels but the view does not refresh to reflect the change.

Also, if I then subsequently make another change to the filter input fields and trigger the $watch handler, it properly updates the view, *including the dataset changes that the $on made but that didn't update to the view earlier.*

WUT.

So, can anyone tell me why calling splitDataChannel from $scope.$watch makes the databinding work properly but the same call triggered by $scope.$on doesn't?

**EDIT**:
I just solved the bug but still don't really understand why this solution is necessary.  I would still love to get feedback.

I added a $apply call to the $on handler:

```
  $scope.$on('columnChange', function(){
    //window resize requires changing column number
    console.log('change detected');
    splitChannelData($rootScope.windowAttr.columns);
    //added this
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

Why does $watch trigger the databinding update while $on does not and the latte requires a manual $apply to be called?

Comment: `$scope.$apply();` is necessary because the event comes from outside of Angular "world", so you need to let app know that event happened.

Comment: OK, I get that 'outside' events need to have $apply called on them but I'm confused by why calling a method inside my controller and manipulating $scope would't 'force' the code execution inside the Angular world.  What exactly defines the boundary of that world?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### General explanation:

"*The boundaries of Angular's world*" is not as complex as it sounds.

A bit simplified, Angular's dirty checking works by storing watchers in an array. A watcher has a watchExpression and a listenerFunction. When the digest cycle is triggered the watchers are iterated. If the returned value of a watchExpression has changed since last time, the associated listenerFunction is executed.

For example a watchExpression returns the string `hello`, while last time it returned `hell`. The listenerFunction is executed to update a specific DOM element's text value with the returned value `hello`.

If you change a variable that is watched but don't trigger the digest cycle, the update will be not reflected in the UI.

If the action **triggers the digest cycle** - You are **inside** the boundaries.

If the action **doesn't trigger the digest cycle** - You are **outside** the boundaries.

Most of the commonly used functionalities in Angular automatically trigger the digest loop internally for you. For example the directive `ngClick` and the `$http` service.

### Specific explanation:

`$broadcast`, `$emit` and `$on` does not trigger the digest cycle. The problem is not with your handler attached to `$on`, but most likely with where `$broadcast` is used.

My guess is that it looks something like this:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function () {
  $rootScope.$broadcast('columnChange');
});
```

The `on` function is a jqLite/jQuery function. It does not trigger the digest cycle, which means it lives outside the boundaries of Angular's world.

You should wrap it in a call to `$apply`:

```
angular.element($window).on('resize', function() {
  $rootScope.$apply(function () { 
    $rootScope.$broadcast('columnChange');
  });
});
```

The reason not to call `$apply` in the handler attached to `$on` is because if something both calls `$broadcast('columnChange')` and triggers the digest loop you will get the `$digest already in progress` error.

Comment: Ah, that's quite helpful.  To make sure I'm understanding it properly:  The dirty checking is not triggered by actual state changes on the databound variables but rather certain events such as UI control interaction or $watch which could, theoretically signal a state change.  Therefore, since Angular isn't watching $on, the downstream changes in the databound variables are irrelevant, Angular doesn't know to start the digest cycle unless manually forced through $apply.  Is that a decent description of what's going on?

Comment: The function `$watch` itself doesn't trigger the digest cycle, it just adds the watchExpression/listenerFunction to the array that is iterated during the cycle. There is nothing in the source code for `$broadcast`/`$on` that triggers the digest cycle, which is why you need to do it manually if you use it in a context that doesn't trigger the cycle itself.

Comment: jqLite/jQuery´s `on` method doesn't trigger it. While the `$broadcast` will work  and run the code, since the digest cycle isn't run afterwards, the databinding will be out of sync and the changes will not be reflected in the UI until the next cycle.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using `ng-model="filter"` on an input. The `ngModel` directive will bind to various events on the input field and everytime it's value changes it will trigger digest to keep databindings synced. And as the digest is run all watchers will be executed, which is why your code in your filter-watch is working.

Comment: That's an awesome explanation, I wish the books I'd read were half that thorough.